# $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(1+\frac{1}{n})^n\cdot n!}{n^n}x^n$ prove if it converge or diverge for $x=-e$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, power-series

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(1+\frac{1}{n})^n\cdot n!}{n^n}x^n$$

Hello, this power series has a radius of $e$, but I cannot conclude if it diverges or converges in $x = -e$, I didn't succeed writing it formally. I would to receive hints or a valid solution, thanks.

Comment: Use Stirling's approximation.

Comment: Leibniz alternate series test.

Comment: i am not familiar with Stirling's approximation is there any other way?

Comment: Try proving that $\frac{n!e^n}{n^n}\to \infty$, or just that it doesn't converge to $0$. Stirling's approximation is just to help you with that.

Answer (score 4):

You can prove that $a_n=\frac{(1+\frac{1}{n})^n\cdot n!}{n^n}e^n$ is a strict increasing sequence. So its limit is not zero and this implies your series is divergent!
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(1+\frac{1}{n+1})^{n+1}\cdot (n+1)!}{{(n+1)}^{n+1}}e^{n+1}\frac{n^n}{e^n(1+\frac{1}{n})^n\cdot n!}
=\frac{(1+\frac{1}{n+1})^{n+1}}{(1+\frac{1}{n})^n}\frac{e}{(1+\frac{1}{n})^n}>1.$$
Here the sequence $\{(1+\frac{1}{n})^n\}$ is strict increasing tending to $e$.

Comment: i did exactly that for x=e but i don't see how the fact that the series diverge for x=e since $  \lim_{n\to \infty} != 0 $ is a sufficient claim for x=-e?

Comment: In both case $x=e$ and $x=-e$, you have the same conclusion  that $\frac{(1+\frac{1}{n})^n\cdot n!}{n^n}x^n$ does not tend to $0$, it is enough to prove the divergence.

Answer (score 3):

Note that

$$\tag 1\ln \left (\frac{n!e^n}{n^n}\right ) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \ln k  + n - n\ln n.$$

Now $\ln x$ is increasing, and this implies $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \ln k \ge \int_1^n \ln x\, dx.$ That integral equals $n\ln n -n +1.$ Thus the expression in $(1) $ is at least $1.$ Therefore $\dfrac{n!e^n}{n^n}$ is at least $e,$ which implies your series diverges.

Answer (score 1):

Use Stirling's approximation as noted by @Robert Z
$$n! \sim \sqrt{2 \pi n} \frac{n^n}{e^n}$$
So
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(1+\frac{1}{n})^n\cdot n!}{n^n}x^n \sim \sqrt{2 \pi}\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n)$$
where $$f(n) = (1+\frac{1}{n})^n\cdot \sqrt{ n} \frac{1}{e^n}x^n$$
For $x = -e$, we have
$$f(n) = (-1)^n(1+\frac{1}{n})^n\cdot \sqrt{ n} $$
Consider
Let's work with $\vert f(n) \vert$
$$g(n) = \log \vert f(n) \vert = \underbrace{n \log(1+\frac{1}{n})}_{\rightarrow 1} + \underbrace{\frac{1}{2} \log n}_{\rightarrow \infty} \rightarrow +\infty$$
So $$\vert f(n) \vert \rightarrow + \infty \neq 0$$
Hence, the series diverges.

Comment: Approximating the sum is not at all formal in this case, as the sum is oscillating.

Comment: Use the absolute value of $x$. State that explicitly.

Comment: @RumpelstiltskinI thought the OP meant for $x = e$. Let me edit as Szeto suggests.

Comment: thanks @Szeto .

Comment: Still, the second line is bothering me. We want to approximate the argument, not the sum itself. Approximating sums like that seems like a bad habit that others might repeat

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin all i'm saying is $\sum a_n$ diverges because $a_n \rightarrow k \neq 0$

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin unless you prove what you say is concrete, i can't follow what you're saying

Comment: $\sum a_n \sim \sum b_n$ should mean that the one converges if and only if the other one does. In general that's not the case. It's the case with sums of positive coefficients. $a_n \sim b_n$ on the other hand means that $a_n/b_n\to 1$. While using the Stirling approximation is a fine approach, one should not compare those sums so recklessly!

Comment: Is there a mathematical definition of "recklessly".. 

What you're saying doesn't make any sense to me. All the terms are positive here in $\vert f(n) \vert$.

Comment: Coefficients of those two sums aren't positive though i. e. $f(n)$ and $\frac{(1+\frac{1}{n})^n\cdot n!}{n^n} x^n$

Answer (score 0):

$f_m(x)
=\sum_{n=1}^{m} \frac{(1+\frac{1}{n})^n\cdot n!}{n^n}x^n
$

(The usual)

$\begin{array}\\
(1+1/n)^n
&=\exp(n\ln(1+1/n))\\
&=\exp(n(1/n-1/(2n^2)+O(1/n^3)))\\
&=\exp(1-1/(2n)+O(1/n^2))\\
&=e\exp(-1/(2n)+O(1/n^2))\\
&=e(1-1/(2n)+O(1/n^2))\\
\end{array}
$

so,
since
$n! \approx cn^{n+1/2}e^{-n}
$,

$\begin{array}\\
f_m(x)
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m} \dfrac{(1+\frac{1}{n})^n\cdot n!}{n^n}x^n\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m} \dfrac{(e(1-1/(2n)+O(1/n^2)))\cdot n!}{n^n}x^n\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m} \dfrac{e n!}{n^n}x^n
-\sum_{n=1}^{m} \dfrac{e\cdot n!}{2n\cdot n^n}x^n
+O(\sum_{n=1}^{m} \dfrac{ n!}{n^2n^n}x^n)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m} \dfrac{e cn^{n+1/2}e^{-n}}{n^n}x^n
-\sum_{n=1}^{m} \dfrac{e\cdot cn^{n+1/2}e^{-n}}{2n\cdot n^n}x^n
+O(\sum_{n=1}^{m} \dfrac{ cn^{n+1/2}e^{-n}}{n^2n^n}x^n)\\
&=ec\sum_{n=1}^{m} \sqrt{n}(x/e)^n
-(ec/2)\sum_{n=1}^{m} n^{-1/2}(x/e)^n
+O(\sum_{n=1}^{m} n^{-3/2}(x/e)^n)\\
\end{array}
$

At $x=e$,
the third series converges,
the second series diverges slowly
like $\sqrt{m}$,
and the first series diverges
like $m^{3/2}$.

So the overall sum diverges.

This holds even if
we take more terms
in the Stirling approximation,
since the first sum remains the same
and only the second sum is changed.

Answer (score 0):

A necessary condition for a series $\sum _{k=0} ^{\infty} a_k $ to converge is that $\lim _{k \rightarrow \infty} a_k =0 $. You can prove this condition does not hold for $x=-e$, hence the power series diverges at $x=-e$. In fact, using Stirling approximation $a_k \approx e\sqrt{2\pi k} \left( \frac{x} {e} \right) ^k$ for $k \rightarrow \infty$.